# Image management system

Tags: php, image, filesystems, photo-gallery

I have a user that wants to be able to upload photo's to his website, and then be able to choose which album he wants them to appear in. I already have the albums hard coded on the site, but he wants the ability to add more.

Does anyone know of a script or cms or something that this can easily and cheaply be implemented or am I going to have to develop all of this from scratch?

Comment: i must not have been able to google the correct terminology then. I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gallery 2](http://gallery.menalto.com/) is my go-to.  It's powering several large website's galleries around the web.

If you're very picky (as several of my clients have been) you can query image information out of the DB and build your own front-end.  I've done several photographer's websites this way.  There is even a desktop upload tool that can be downloaded if desired.

There is no cost at all.

Answer (score 0):

For Image management I have used and recommend http://coppermine-gallery.net/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the cheapest and most complete solution I found. [Slick Gallery](http://www.zinescripts.com/products/slickgallery/)

This one also seems like it would work well
[PhotoCMS](http://codecanyon.net/item/-photocms-manage-your-portfolio-easily/62023)